# How to check if record field is empty using just the component syntax?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, record, aura-if

Using `force:recordData` to load a record data to a component, how can I check if a numeric field is `null`, to work with the `aura:if` syntax?

I've tried `!= null`, `!= undefined`, `!= ''`, `empty(v.record.field__c)`, but none of those seem to work.

Comment: I just verified `!=null`, it just works fine. As an example -- `<aura:if isTrue="{!v.simpleRecord.NumberOfEmployees != null}">` and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your syntax for the first three...

if your `force:recordData`'s `targetFields="{! v.simpleRecord }"`

Wouldn't your expression check just be:

`not(empty( v.simpleRecord.field__c ))`

Comment: Actually, you are correct. For some reason, when using multiple conditions, if this check is the last parameter, then it doesn't work. I tried with the `empty` only, and it worked, then added other conditions after it and wrapped it all in an `and`, just like before, but keeping the `empty` first. Weird. Thank you!

Comment: That's a really good find... I was just about to edit this post and say that even according to the [reference docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm), technically Integers / Decimals aren't supported with `empty()`. But maybe it's treated as a String in the `simpleRecord.field__c`